# How to copy a remote file with Guzzle in WebDAV?

Tags: php, webdav, guzzle

I am trying to understand how to copy a file on a remote WebDAV server to another location on that same server by using Guzzle. I currently have

```
$client->request('COPY', 'file1.txt', [
    'Destination' => 'file2.txt',
    'Overwrite' => 'T',
]);
```

This method is giving me a 400 response

```
    Client error: 'COPY http://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/admin/file1.txt' resulted in a '400 Bad Request' response:
```

file1.txt does exist and it's not a permissions issue.

I'm following some docs* and trying to guess my way to get it working as I can't find any examples online.

Can anyone let me know what I need to change?

*eg https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The Destination and Overwrite parameters need to be sent in the headers.

```
$headers = [
    'Destination' => 'file2.txt',
    'Overwrite' => 'T',
]);
$client->request('COPY', 'file1.txt', [
    'headers' => $headers,
]);
```

There seems to be a real lack of documentation on WebDAV.